# How do I extract parts of a cell inside an R dataframe to save them in a different column?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I need to extract the year from vote_data and save it into another column to finally sort the dataframe by year. [image: R dataframe]

Anyone with an idea? If it is possible to sort it without extracting, that would be even better. Already tried sorting, but did not find out how to sort only by year when the cell contains the whole date.

Comment: It's . asier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `arrange()` from the **dplyr** package:

```
df = data.frame(
       vote_id = 1:3,
       vote_date = c("1975-04-25","1976-04-25","1974-04-25")
)

dplyr::arrange(df, df$vote_date)
dplyr::arrange(df, desc(df$vote_date)) # Descendent
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
    mutate(year = year(ymd(vote_date))) %>%
    arrange(year)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org) package, I believe it has the functions you're looking for!

Comment: Please avoid [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Try to include enough information to be able to help the user should the link ever disappear.